# Information on Maps-iOS SDK for Apple Privacy Nutrition label

Tags: google-maps, sdk, google-maps-sdk-ios

Wanted to get information on **Maps-iOS SDK** for Apple Privacy Nutrition label. Google's official documentation is not updated : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/apple-privacy-policy

If anyone knows this or can point to a resource, will help a lot.

Comment: Could you please report this in Google Public Issue Tracker? Here is the [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188833&template=789005) for the appropriate component.

Comment: Thanks @rafon, I have raised issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/212504747